# What does elite mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

In many Adventure Paths or specific books I find this "Elite" sorta template on creatures, but if memory serves me I've never actually found descriptions about what's the difference between a standard creature and an elite one. So that's the question, what is the difference between a standard creature and an elite one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Elite" isn't a [template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/) the way that [Lycanthrope](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/lycanthrope/) and [Half-Fiend](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/half-fiend/) are. Rather, "elite" is a descriptor, to indicate that the described creature is somehow a cut above the rest of their kind. In my experience, they're typically used as mini-bosses, squad leaders, etc..

There are two major ways I've found recently that a creature can become elite: the addition of class levels (eg., the [Elite Kobold](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/unique-monsters/cr-1/black-claw-elite-kobold-warrior-4/) gains 4 levels of [Warrior](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/npc-classes/warrior)) or fiat (eg., the [Elite Bronze Giant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/unique-monsters/cr-12/argbadh-karambagya-elite-bronze-giant/) is just a [Bronze Giant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/giants/giant-true/giant-bronze) with some tweaked stats and default gear). I seem to recall seeing some Elite creatures that had additional racial HD, but I'm not finding them at the moment; it's probable that that was more of a D&D 3.0/3.5 thing.

The easiest way to make a regular creature into an elite version is probably the [Simple Advanced Template](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/advanced-creature-cr-1/) and/or one of the [Simple Class Templates](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-class-templates/).